# Recommendation for processors specialized for rendering and encoding

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, rendering

I have a *"Intel Pentium CPU G2030 @ 3.0GHz"* processor, and a *"Intel HD Graphics"* graphics card.

> **General CPU info**
>
> > Cores = 2
> >     Threads = 2
> >     Bus speed = 99.76MHz
> >     Max TDP = 55.0W
> >     Core Speed = ~3GHz

> **General GPU info**
>
> > GPU = GT1
> >     GPU clock = 650 MHz
> >     Transistors = 1.4 B
> >     Bandwidth = 21.3GB/s
> >     Multi-GPU = Disabled

> **Time taken for a 30 mins video to encode (h.264) with handbrake**
>   **(Using all CPU cores)**
>
> > 2-pass, profile=main, preset=slow : 1hr 30mins
> >     2-pass, profile=main, preset=medium : 1hr
> >     2-pass, profile=main, preset=fast : 45mins
> >     2-pass, profile=main, preset=very fast(handbrake "normal" default) : 25mins

I don't know much about processors or graphics card, and I don't know which is better at rendering + encoding. Could you recommend some of it for me? Prices below $200, and TDP below 80 would be great. Thanks.

Comment: heh. No offence but that processor is *seriously* on the low end. That said, quicksync does wonders for re-encoding. Is that an option?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Besides QuickSync, are there any more options?

Comment: Not too sure, I don't actually use  vegas, but I experimented with a handbrake fork with quicksync.

Comment: So do you already have a whole computer? What's your motherboard? Power supply?

Comment: @Alpha3031 Yes I have. `Motherboard: ECS H61H2-M17 , Power Supply: ATX-500W`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPU is usually faster, but I cannot find GPU benchmarks for Handbrake, so I'll recommend a CPU. Keep in mind that using the CPU I recommend, you need a new motherboard.

I'd recommend an AMD FX-8320E. The 8320 because it's practically AMD's top of the line, and the 'E' because that basically means it's better binned, and they are both the same price at the moment.

Other popular AMD CPUs such as the 8350, 8370, 9370, and 9590 are basically overclocked versions of this, but I can't bother to provide a link, so you'll have to search it up or not believe me.

I recommend AMD, also, because of better price/performance ratio. As you can see in this [anandtech benchmark](http://www.anandtech.com/bench/product/1198?vs=1403), the overclocked FX-8320E ($125) is on par with the non-overclocked i5 4690 ($200). Overclocking Intel CPUs would probably surpass performance, but not by anything worth $200, which is already at your budget, so you wouldn't be able to buy a new motherboard.

I know that some people are going to point out that it is hard to upgrade an FX-8320E to anything, due to an outdated chipset, but I don't think that 'dark fang' is going to be upgrading any time in the near future.

Unfortunately, when using an AMD CPU, you are going to have the disadvantage of not having a built it GPU. You can either get a motherboard with on-board video, or a cheap dedicated GPU.

I'd recommend a motherboard with a built-in GPU, which I know everyone thinks is terrible, but looked at his current iGPU. A nice, overclocking motherboard such as [this](http://pcpartpicker.com/part/gigabyte-motherboard-ga990fxaud3r5), would be ideal for getting the most performance out of your CPU as well as getting an integrated GPU, but a more budget-friendly option could be [this](http://pcpartpicker.com/part/gigabyte-motherboard-ga78lmtusb3) instead. I know option #2 isn't the greatest, but it is cheap. If anyone else has a motherboard suggestion, comment and I'll edit into my answer.